# Mobile Testing Tools

Tags: mobile-automation

I have investigated several mobile testing tools to test our mobile application. Unfortunately, I have not found a tool that can meet the following requirements. If anyone has suggested a tool(s) that will be appreciated.

Our requirements are:

- Support record/replay for automation testing

Appium and Selenium are very developer based and my skills in writing code are not on this level (setup is quite complex). I looking for more user friendly automation tool.

Comment: You've mentioned requirement~S~, but only mentioned one. Would you have something else to add?

Answer (score 1):

Try with below

TestComplete Mobile – SmartBear (Android and iOS)
SeeTest Continuous Testing Platform (Android and iOS)
Katlon Recorder

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you can use Espresso Test Recorder (included in Android Studio as part of Android Espresso) ([description](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/espresso-test-recorder), [short video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JRkDVvB106k)).

Answer (score -1):

Try out Ranorex Studio https://www.ranorex.com/

I have used it for Desktop Testing but I know that they support mobile testing as well. They have the option to use code-modules or recording (record and replay) as well.